# Crash on iPhone 5C only

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine

I made an app with Unity in C#, built it on xCode and is now on sale in the Apple Store. It works fine in most iPhones and iPads, but it keeps crashing for one user that has an iPhone 5C. The app opens up but before completing loading it crashes. Another user with 5C has it working.

I have asked the user to update the software, delete the app and re-install it, but still crashes.

Do you have any idea on what may be the reason?

Comment: I think it is issue with iOS version, ask your customers to update the iOS version. They may have lower iOS version.

Comment: Update iphone 5C version to latest iOS 10.3 version.

Comment: Her iOS is up to date. Maybe is because the app is very heavy? 130 MB